# Some problems about using ajax to submit form data into MySQL then change page in phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app, and I am trying to submit my sign up form and send the data into MySQL through ajax, then after submit I wanna pop up a page to inform the user whether it is successes. I can send the data and get a popup page but it seems like I have something wrong to get the dialogY page which will show on the below.

This is my html

```
    <html> 
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height
    <link some css here….>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/signup.js"></script>
     <script>

    function onBodyLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }

    </script>
    <title>DTSB System</title>
</head>
```

continue

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="signinpage" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Sign in</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <form name="signinform" id="signinform" align="center" method="post" action="home.html" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" name="fusername1" id="fusername1" placeholder="Username" class="required">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="password" name="fpasswd1" id="fpasswd1" placeholder="Password" class="required">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="signinsubmit" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-u-r" data-transition="flip" value="Sign in">
        <a href="#signuppage" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" data-transition="slidedown">Sign up</a>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>IZUMEI</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="signuppage" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" >
    <form name="signupform" id="signupform" align="center">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="fusername2">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fusername2" id="fusername2" class="required" minlength="3">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="fpasswd2">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="fpasswd2" id="fpasswd2" class="required" minlength="5">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="fconfirmpasswd">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="fconfirmpasswd" id="fconfirmpasswd" class="required passmatch" minlength="5">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="femail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="femail" id="femail" class="required">
        </div>
                <input id="register" type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Registration">
        <a href="#signinpage" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="slideup">Cancel</a>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>IZUMEI</h1>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-role="page" id="dialogY" data-theme="a" data-dialog="true">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Successfully sign up</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p align="center">Congradulations!Welcome to be one of us!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" align="center" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#signinpage" type="button">Sign in now</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="dialogN" data-theme="a" data-dialog="true" data-rel="back">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Sign up failed</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p align="center">Sorry, something wrong when sign up, <span>please try again later</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fusername2']);
$password=sha1($_POST['fpasswd2']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['femail']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pass, user_email)";
$sql .= "VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";

$exist = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name= '". $username . "'";
$query_result = mysql_query($exist, $con);

if(mysql_num_rows($query_result) == 0) {
if(isset($username)&& isset($password) && isset($email)){
    if(mysql_query($sql, $con)){
        echo "Insert success!";
    }else{
        die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}else{
    die ('Error: There are empty fields needed to be filled' . mysql_error());
}
}else{
die ('Error: User already exist' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is my js file

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#signuppage", function() {
$.validator.addMethod("passmatch", function(value) {
return value == $("#fpasswd2").val();
}, 'Confirmation password must match.');
});


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#signupform').validate();

$('#signupform').submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: formData,
    url:'http://localhost/doctor/insert_info.php',
    cache: false ,
    success: function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("#dialogY");
    }
    error: function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("#dialogN");
    }
    });

    return false;
}); 
});
```

I have tried a lot of methods but I still can't get the dialogY page, It seems like I can not get the success feedback, even if I submit the right data. When I run these codes in emulator it works, but on safari it fails. Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Are all of the assets being served from "localhost" (which I see in the ajax call)?  If not Safari may be failing due to [the Same-Origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Just make sure you are pointing all of our resources at the same hostname.

When you turn on error reporting in Safari are you seeing anything in the console?

Comment: The console said XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/doctor/insert_info.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. but in the config.xml I have changed the <access origin="*" />. Is this a problem or shall I change it to <access origin="http://localhost/.."?

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I checked my code and added header('Access-Contorl-Allow-Origin: *') in my php file then I solve the problem! I appreciate your answer anyway. :-)

Comment: Glad you got it solved. From a security stand point it would be better to use the same domain for all requests as I suggested rather than loosen the security with the PHP header.  Does modifying the ajax to omit the domain work, like so: url:'/doctor/insert_info.php'

Comment: If I omit the domain work then the page don't work anymore, I put my php files in the xampp htdocs directory and html,js,css in the phonegap project directory.

Comment: It was so weird, after I adding header, I only can get the dialogY page but can not get the dialogN page, any idea about this?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma after the *success: function(){},*